# Why AndroidStudio shows warning "Namespace declaration is never used"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-namespaces

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Taked from the [android official training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#LinearLayout)

In the second line, AndroidStudio shows this warning:

```
Namespace declaration is never used
```

Why this happens?

Thank you.

Comment: The statement that the tools namespace is not used is perfectly correct, but I've no idea why the parser chooses to report this as a warning, since unused namespaces normally do no harm.

Comment: Yes, But I think having an unused namespace is like having an unused variable or method. So by default the ide warns the unnecessary code.

Comment: Well, warnings are a matter of opinion, but so many XML-generation processes produce XML with redundant namespaces that in my view, a tool that warns about them is going to get very irritating. Also, you can't automatically detect that a namespace declaration is redundant; it might be used only (as in XSLT) to declare prefixes used by QNames-in-content.

Comment: How you said, "warnings are a matter of opinion". In my opinion is good thing the ide warns unused things, even in xml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you don't have anything with `tools` namespace actually declared in your xml.

Look at the `android` namespace, you have 3 elements with that namespace, but none for `tools`.

The namespace `tools` (http://schemas.android.com/tools) is used for the GUI designer and is not used for running apps on Android devices so you can safely remove it.

Answer (score 1):

just remove "xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto""

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32001479)